# Wifi not working after cleaning the computer?

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I cleaned up inside the computer and now I no longer see the WiFi icon and it's not working. I tried to check the box **do not use the device** in **Software & Update** in **Additional Driver** tab then reboot. Next, I checked the box **Using DKMS source for...** again then reboot. I still can't get my wifi working.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? How did you clean the computer?

Comment: i use version 20.04 , i cleaning dust into the computer

Comment: Probably now the contact is bad. Take the wireless adapter out, clean it and place back.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem for myself using the following operations :

`cd rtl8821ce`

`sudo make all`

`sudo make install`

then i reboot and i see wifi icon back . Thanks for care